# AppcompatActivity: OutMemoryException

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

Asking this question again with some more details. 
we recently switched to using AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentActivity and now some devices are randomly crashing with the following error. No idea why this is happening.

The stack trace shows it crashes on calling the super.onCreate() of the AppCompatActivity.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 16008012 byte allocation with 4277152 free bytes and 4MB until OOM
   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(VMRuntime.java)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(BitmapFactory.java)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:703)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:733)
   at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(BitmapDrawable.java:779)
   at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:741)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:2549)
   at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:254)
   at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:164)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:2549)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:2320)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4210)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4089)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:2005)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1987)
   at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:464)
   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(SourceFile:3026)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(SourceFile:200)
   at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(SourceFile:81)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(SourceFile:127)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(SourceFile:147)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(SourceFile:27)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(SourceFile:53)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.(SourceFile:29)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(SourceFile:203)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(SourceFile:185)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(SourceFile:525)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:74)
   at com.dubizzle.horizontal.activities.AbstractActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:98)
   at com.dubizzle.horizontal.activities.ItemPhotoViewer.onCreate(SourceFile:68)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here is the structure: 
ItemPhotoViewer onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // calls the AbstractActivity onCreate
// a bunch of other things
}
```

AbstractActivity onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // this calls AppcomPatActivity onCreate    
     //and crashes.
    // some initializations
}
```

Comment: You need to show more, the problem might be somewhere else. As an advice, try to remove stuff step by step until you narrow down the problem.

Comment: @KNeerajLal I am showing some images from the server in a viewpager using the PhotoView library but it doesn't even get there. Crashes on super

Comment: @AndreiT see above comment. Bw it only started after we switched to AppcompatActivity

Comment: I understand that. But you need to try to find where exactly this happen, because as I can see it looks like you have some images that you are loading somewhere. Not sure what is the connection between AppCompatActivity and your code, but you need to debug it a bit more in order to find the problem. From what you posted I cannot spot the problem.

Comment: @AndreiT Thanks. I wish i could post the relevant code. But i have no idea because the stack trace doesn't say anything. Plus, i haven't been able to reproduce it on any testing devices. It happens on our live version for some users

Comment: Are you using proguard? If so, try to check if u need to update something.

Comment: @AndreiT yes i am using proguard. But that should make it crash for all users. right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132366/discussion-between-andrei-t-and-sayed-hassan).

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again. Go back and edit your other question if you have more details, or delete your original question and create a new one.

Answer (score -2):

add

`android:largeHeap="true"`

in the AndroidManifest application tag